# sudo dpkg --configure -a takes forever

Tags: gnome, 17.04

Can it be that `sudo dpkg --configure -a` takes more then 10 minutes? I got an error with NVIDIA and now everything is broken it stops right at the first line:

base-files (9.6ubuntu13.1) ...

I am using Gnome Ubuntu 17.03 with Kernel 4.10.0-37

PS: I ran

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get -f install
```

before using the dpkg command.

Comment: Try `sudo dpkg -D1 --configure -a` to see if it's really stuck or just doing something. I don't think 10 minutes is too long to reconfigure all the installed packages.

Comment: It shows : D000001: ensure_diversions: new, (re) loading
D000001: process queue pkg base-files:amd64 queue.len 1 progress 1, try 1...

Comment: This is now 20 minutes - no change yet. No error, no going forward... This doesn´t look normal to me